# Navigation Drawer app behaivour when open fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, navigation-drawer

Im working with a Android app that uses Navigation Drawer. This app use the template provided with Eclipse ADT (when you select the navigation drawer template).

I dont understand the behaivour of the navigation drawer very well.

My main requeriment is make a "search" option, I have on the Navigation Drawer a EditText to get the query string from the user. I want that I press search button and open my SearchFragment getting the search query.

I know that I can make this:

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("searchQuery",searchQuery);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
```

And this for getting:

```
    getArguments().getString("searchQuery");
```

But I have the next:

- MainActivity
- NavigationDrawerFragment
- SearchFragment
- OtherFragments.. (I think this arent relevant in the question)

I dont understand where I can make this steps.

More data:
I have in the navigation drawer class the EditText with the setOnEditorActionListener for the search press.

Any info that I can add I will be add. Sorry my english

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawer is basically a component that show 2 pane in the way that one is the main pane (usually fragment) that is used to show content and the other one is usually a listview that is just used to choose which fragment to show in main pane
so if you want to switch between 2 different layouts you have to create 2 different fragments and then you can add or replace these fragments based on listview's selected item.
You may refer to below link for complete code
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, But I dont know How I can send my data from my EditText (on my Navigation drawer) to my main fragment (and open it on same time). I have to make a "search" option, when you press search, the navigation closes and the searchfragment must be opened (and receive the search string)

Comment: so we have a searchedittext box and a searchbutton in left pane and a resulttextbox in right pane

first of all get all the elements(searchedittext, searchbutton, resulttextbox, navigationdrawer) using findViewById

in onclick method of searchbutton set value of searchedittext to resulttextbox and call navigationdrawer.closedrawer()
navigationdrawer.closedrawer will close the left pane(searchbox pane) and show the right pane(searchresult pane)